# Dropbox ServerException In Android

Tags: android, dropbox

I am trying to send text file to dropbox but i dont know why there is some error comes out showing Dropbox ServerException.

My **program works till complete the authentication** but,,
after that it goes to DropboxException showing the error and

```
mDBApi.putFileOverwrite(filePath, new FileInputStream(file), file.length(), null);
```

won't get executed.

Here is my LogCat :

```
 12-26 10:27:24.214: W/System.err(1154): DropboxServerException (nginx): 403 Forbidden (Forbidden)
 12-26 10:27:24.224: W/System.err(1154):    at com.dropbox.client2.RESTUtility.parseAsJSON(RESTUtility.java:263)
 12-26 10:27:24.224: W/System.err(1154):    at com.dropbox.client2.RESTUtility.execute(RESTUtility.java:411)
 12-26 10:27:24.224: W/System.err(1154):    at com.dropbox.client2.DropboxAPI$BasicUploadRequest.upload(DropboxAPI.java:1081)
```

`

I searched on google there is nothing for this.

here is the link for my whole program.

[1] [com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxUnlinkedException

All Dropbox Experts, Plz Help me to solve this. ( ',' )

Comment: possible duplicate of [com.dropbox.client2.exception.DropboxUnlinkedException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20780729/com-dropbox-client2-exception-dropboxunlinkedexception)

Comment: I have checked out my whole program but there is no duplications of that code. This new error comes out now :
`12-27 05:30:43.293: W/System.err(937): DropboxServerException (nginx): 403 Forbidden (Forbidden)` @smarx


And some one given -1 vote kindly check it, its another error this is the another issue.

Comment: I marked this as a potential duplicate of an earlier question of yours. I also gave the -1 vote.

Comment: I really know you are very much senior and i appreciate that sir, but this is the another problem not that one. 
I have edited that question and given it as a total answer properly on that,
But
now **`12-27 05:30:43.293: W/System.err(937): DropboxServerException (nginx): 403 Forbidden (Forbidden)`** this error comes out. Please help me to solve this. @smarx

Comment: Someone please reply me on this. What should i do ????

Comment: You should stop using multiple "????" when asking a question/for help. People are more likely to help if you are clear, don't seem like you are rushing them, etc. Check your other version(s) of this question. I left a comment that says I think you are confusing the use of the filePath variable. I think filePath should be the path and file name on Dropbox, where you are giving it the file path from your phone. That could be causing the 403 Forbidden.

Comment: OK sir, Thx for all type of help. I will follow all the instructions onward. And about my problem, you mean to say that filePath is **path given For Dropbox** is it? And if is it so, I have done changes (putFileOverwrite("Dropbox.txt",..) but still it showing the same error. @ wormtown

Comment: As I tried a lot to do this I got the same error so if any one can solve this please give your Email-ID i will send you all the details over-there. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
AndroidAuthSession session = new AndroidAuthSession(appKeys,ACCESS_TYPE);
```

1.check `AndroidAuthSession` connection use `isLinked()`

2.check `AccessType`, in my case I use `AccessType.APP_FOLDER` will fail(403 Forbidden) 
  but `AccessType.DROPBOX` is fine

Comment: I think you accidentally copied pasted twice. What is the second `AccessType.APP_FOLDER` supposed to be?